# How to detect URL scheme and prevent the default navigation to that URL in phonegap hybrid application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have the following requirement for my application (Android, iOS):

When the application launches it displays a login.html page (which is part of the application). After logging in, the application's webview should be occupied with home.jsp from an external domain. When user clicks on logout button in home.jsp it has to navigate back to login page . On click of logout when we use`window.location.href="login.html"` then it tries to find the page on xxx domain.

Is there a way to detect this navigation URL and override the URL from javascript or phonegap properties in the application?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. 1) How do you load home.jsp to begin with in your application? 2) You say you login in login.html - which is **part of your application** but then you load home.jsp which is **from an external domain**, so how does it know you are actually logged in? and how does it know you're actually logged out? 2 separate pages, 2 separate domains, sounds like a recipe for XSS vulnerability. 3) What is your Worklight version+build?

Comment: You can override the WebView's methods that catch URL requests, let us know which version of Worklight. However, it seems to me like 99% of your application happens on an external server, in which case, why not push it to 100% by making login.html be on your external server as well? That way - no need to go back and forth between the 2.

Comment: @IdanAdar- 1) In login.html I have a form submission, where after submitting login form the server will return 302 redirect response and there after it will redirect to home.jsp page. Which indicates the login.html will be replaced with home.jsp in web view. 2) Hope the first answer can be a answer for this also. 3) My worklight version is 6.2.0.00-20140719-1643.

Comment: @NathanH - Yes I can push the login page also to the external server however as per our application architecture the login page has to be placed locally. May be we will move that to server in later stage. Currently I am using worklight 6.2.0.00-20140719-1643 version. It will be helpful if you can tell me the logic to override the URL requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to vary depending on how you've implemented the mentioned WebView where home.jsp is being displayed in. You did not provide any code or any specific information so the answer is going to be the same - somewhat vague...

---

1. If you've opened a new WebView, then you can't control it from JavaScript. You'll need to control it via Java or Objective-C code (you did not mention which environment you're developing for...).

   For example, if you'll look in the your-app\android\native\src\com\your-app\your-app.java file, you'll see how the native layer loads the application's index.html file after the Worklight JavaScript framework has been loaded.

   Similarly, you could re-use this approach in your own application to close and re-load login.html.
2. If you're in fact doing the mentioned re-direct from the comments, meaning you're re-using the current webview but replacing its content with external content, then I think it is expected that you've lost the context of the application, and when looking for login.html - it doesn't find it... because you've moved from app-context to web-context. They do not know each other.

   I think you should not do this re-direct. Instead, you need to open a new WebView using a Cordova plug-in, and in this new WebView to display your external content.

   In this Overlayed WebView, you can detect any urls that are clicked on and if the sign-out URL was detected, then close the WebView.

   You can see parts of this in action in the [Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/integrating-server-generated-pages-hybrid-applications/) and accompanying sample project.

   In the sample project, you can see the functions provided (where you can add yours) in android\nativeResources\src\com\IncludeExternalPages\IncludeExternalPages.java.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect window.location.href in an android emulator I get file:///android_asset/www/index.html

But I think Nathans idea of moving it to the server is a good one. You could also have one on the device  if you really need to. (PErhaps you should ask the person specifiying the app achitecture how they would do it :) )